# Pandas .groupby(): aggregation to include grouping variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My Data:

```
a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, ...
0,   0,   1,   0,  ...
1,   0,   0,   1,  ...
1,   1,   1,   0,  ...
0,   1,   0,   0,  ...
etc...
```

I want to sum all the rows for each column, looping through `if a_1 == 1` then `if b_1 == 1` then `if c_1 == 1` etc.

right now I have `testDict = {k : df[df[k + '_1']==1].groupby(k + '_1').sum() for k in letters}`

However, this sums all the columns except the column I am grouping by... which I also want the sum for. Any thoughts or suggestions?

The output should look like:

```
testDict['a'] : 
a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2,  ...
2,   1,   1,   1, ...

testDict['b'] :
a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2,  ...
1,   1,   2,   0,  ....
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post expected output? and more rows of input data?

Comment: @john galt is that better? Another possible solution for my question is `testDict = {k : df[df[k + '_1']==1].groupby().sum() for k in letters}` but `.groupby` requires a parameter

Comment: @johngalt ahhh i figured it out, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh whoops I totally missed this. I can just use `testDict = {k : df[df[k + '_1']==1].sum() for k in letters}` with no groupby! durrrr.

I ended up with `testDict = {k : pd.DataFrame(df[df[k + '_1']==1].sum()).transpose() for k in letters}` to maintain the horizontal layout (`.sum()` created a vertical layout)